# Codeigniter : a href with hash not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, href, fragment-identifier

Im now developing a websites with a number of internal links present in each page. the project is in codeigniter.

on some part of the html code , i used anchor links for internal linking like

`<a href="http://something.com/products/product_1/features/#quality">Quality</a>`

there is a `<div id="quality">Product Quality</div>` in the

`http://something.com/products/product_1/features` page .

But when im clicking on this link , nothing will happen (other a href with normal links are working).i done this same process in my previous projects , but they are in php without any framework. is there any problem with using hash in href links in codeigniter.?

Suggest me some solution. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What if the link is `http://something.com/products/product_1/features#quality`?

Comment: There are no issue with code igniter and anchor tags, try what @chris85 suggested and let us know.

Comment: if the link is http://something.com/products/product_1/features#quality , i assumed that the page is redirected to the quality section (<div id="quality">some content</div>) of features page.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure your routes

CI2 http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

CI3 http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

```
$route['products/product_1/features/(:any)'] = 'products/product_1/features/$1';
```

Make sure you have allowed hash application/config/config.php

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=&?#';
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/docs